# How getRequestDispatcher will work for Sub-Folder JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using getRequestDispatcher() function for passing notification message to a jsp page after perform any operation in JSP Servlet. But the method works fine when i pass message to a root directory JSP page But it doesn't work for a sub folder directory file in the same project.

**This Works Fine (for root directory Page) -**

---

```
request.setAttribute("Message", "Message Text" );
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Index.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

---

**But its not work(for sub-folder directory Page) -**

```
**request.setAttribute("Message", "Message Text" );
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Folder/Index.jsp").forward(request,response);**
```

I attached an image of my project structure-
I want to send message with getRequestDispatcher() to a page whic is under admin folder. but the Response URL stack at **http://localhost:8080/ALPMS/Servlet**

[image]
What should i have to change in ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: could you post folder structure of your app ?

Comment: Thanks, I attached an image in question body , please watch it  ...

Comment: There is no folder named "Folder" in your web app. So why would that work? Also, don't just say "it doesn't work". Post the exact and complete error you get. Or, if no error, describe precisely what you're doing, and what happens.

Comment: I just used **"Folder"** word not any specific folder  because it can be any folder name(for my application like **admin**, **users**), so i just name it as a Folder.

** AND the error is ** the redirect to specific page is not work it stack at servlet url but no specific error...

Comment: A forward is not a redirect. The URL in your location bar will never change due to a forward. If you want help, post **real** code.

Comment: after perform operation it stack in this link ( *http://localhost:8080/ALPMS/GlobalServlet*  )  ALPMS is my project name and GlobalServlet is my servlet name ...... 

But i ussed the bellow code after operation to give a success message on same page from where i submitted a form ..

`**request.setAttribute("Message", "Message Text" );
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/admin/our_instructors.jsp").forward(request,response);**`

Comment: i already used *crossContext="true"* in tomcat content.xml file .

Comment: So, what is the problem? Is the problem that you're not seeing the HTML that the JSP is supposed to generate? Or that you're seeing it, but without the message? Or that you expect the location bar to display our_instructors.jsp, and it displays GlobalServlet instead? If the latter, again, it's perfectly normal. A forward is NOT a redirect. It happens at server side, and the browser doesn't know nor care.

Comment: i want to send a notification message to the same page where from i submitted form , after my database operation is done in servlet  . I generally use  getServletContext() and it works fine only for root jsp pages but not working for the sub-folder jsp pages . 
So i need suggestions how it can works or similer methods or way to pass notification in servlet to jsp page .